# Divide and conquer algorithm problem applied to an n x n-matrix

Tags: algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

A total of n players have competed in a chess tournament. In particular every pair of players i and j played one single game. All results of the tournament are encoded in a n × n-matrix A, where for every pair of different players A[i, j] encodes the result of the game that i and j played in the following way:

```
A[i, j] =
Option 1: i if i wins
Option 2: 0 draw
Option 3: j if j wins
```

We say that a player d is a superchampion if she has won all her games. We would like an algorithm that receives A as input and returns a superchampion d if exists. If there is no superchampion then the algorithm must return 0.
Give a divide-and-conquer algorithm for the task. It is enough to obtain a O(n log n) . In your algorithm is perfectly fine to consider the matrix A to be global variable so that it does not need to be included in the input of each recursive call.

I assume each player plays once against other players. Also, the diagonal will contain 0's as each player cannot play against herself, and the matrix will be symmetric. In addition, I think the base case would be that we only have 1 player, so that player will be the superchampion. However, I do not know how to check for a superplayer, i.e., how to check the rows and columns of the matrix without a double for loop, which would result in O(n^2).

Comment: If you're allowed to write whatever you want in the diagonal, then personally I would set A[i, i] = i for the diagonal. Since we're only interested in the existence of a superchampion, it's convenient to be able to say that a superchampion is a player i such that A[i, j] = i for all j

Comment: Also, be careful if you write this program in an actual programming language: pretty much every programming language except R uses 0-based indexing, which means there will be a player i = 0 in your matrix, so encoding draws with 0 and winner by the index of the winner is not the best idea ever.

Comment: @Stef I just need to write the pseudocode for the problem

Comment: The trick here is not to think about an algorithm that finds the super champion, but instead think about proving that no player is a super champion. For example, given players A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H, examine the pairs (A,B), (C,D), (E,F), (G,H). If A beat B, C beat D, E beat F, and G beat H, then you know that B,D,F,H are **not** super champions. I leave it to you to figure out the rest.